# Azure B2C SAML-RP implementation does not work

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I want to implement authentication over Azure B2C and use local accounts and redirect to my application with SAML response.

I follow:

1. https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/master/Walkthroughs/RP-SAML.md
2. [MS Azure AD B2C as SAML IDP not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46475738/ms-azure-ad-b2c-as-saml-idp-not-working)
3. I did test over Postman and received that error "AADB2C: An exception has occured". After setup logging over AppInsite -> error message:

   **Request does not contain any SAML 2.0 protocol parameters**

   Over postman I sent below request:

   POST  https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/matonokb2c.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_signin/samlp/sso/login?SAML_Request=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&RelayState=http://localhost:44316/saml

SAML_Request contains base64 encoded auth.request:

```
<samlp:AuthnRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" ID="F84D888AA3B44C1B844375A4E8210D9E" 
Version="2.0" IsPassive="false" AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://localhost:44316/saml">
<Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" /><samlp:NameIDPolicy Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified" /></samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

**UPDATE**

1. Test SAML Request created over [SamlTool-Example](https://www.samltool.com/generic_sso_req.php)
2. Update per Idp settings ( entityId/Issuer)
3. Deflate/Base64/Url encoding
4. B2C proper query string is **?SAMLRequest=request**, not SAML_Request as in above instuction

Thanks

Comment: Please verify your AuthnRequest, it doesn't match the saml-schema-protocol-2.0.xsd. You can use tool such as this to verify: https://www.samltool.com/validate_authn_req.php

Comment: Thanks, works great. For who will work with b2c I added test saml request and example after deflation/url encode ( that part I misseed too).